# Updating multiple instances of text spans using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make some tools for myself with dynamic HTML pages using JavaScript. I have been trying to update text in an HTML form, and while I can update a single piece of text, I cannot update any more.

Below is some sample code from my project which demonstrates this problem. The code is a collection of snippets I pieced together from other code samples.

I have tried to find an answer, but my JavaScript level is basic.

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function changeText(element) {
  document.getElementById('initname').innerHTML = element.value;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 75%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Test thing</h2>
  <p>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" onkeyup="changeText(this)" name="first name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required="required" class="input-txt" />
    </form>
  </p>
  <p>tabs of sentences</p>

  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab 1')">Tab 1</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab 2')">Tab 2</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab 3')">Tab 3</button>
  </div>

  <div id="Tab 1" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Hello, my name is <b><span id="initname";>First and Last</span></b> number 1 and I really wish all instances of my name would update when I type in the above text field.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Tab 2" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Hello, my name is <b><span id="initname";>First and Last</span></b> number 2 and I really wish all instances of my name would update when I type in the above text field.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Tab 3" class="tabcontent">
    <p>Hello, my name is <b><span id="initname";>First and Last</span></b> number 3 and I really wish all instances of my name would update when I type in the above text field.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()` rather than concatenating and deleting from `.className`.

Comment: `.className = "..."` overwrites the element existing class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spaces in the `id`s, `Tab 1`, `Tab 2`, and `Tab 3`. This is not a good idea. I removed them from the `div`s and from the `openTab(event, 'Tab X')` calls above.

There are three `<span>`s with the same `id` of `initname`. Elements should each have unique `id`s. You could give each element a different `id`, but in this case, it would be better to change those `id`s to `class`. This will be used later to fix another problem.

For ease of comparing the sentences, I changed the first word of each sentence so that it is more clear that the text changes when you click on a tab.

As mentioned in the comments to your question, you had a space in your class name `" active"`, so it should be removed in two places. Also, the correct way to `remove` and `add` classes is as follows:

```
.classList.remove("active");
.classList.add("active");
```

When you type a name into the input field it should change the name in all of the `span`s. So, I used the same code structure you used to loop through each `span` to change each element's `innerHTML` to the new value being entered into the `input` field.

Please note that I used `let` and `const` instead of `var`.

I used `innerHTML` because you did before, but `textContent` can also be used.

```js
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
}

function changeText(element) {
  const initnames = document.getElementsByClassName("initname");
  for (let i = 0; i < initnames.length; i++) {
    initnames[i].innerHTML = element.value;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 75%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Test thing</h2>
<p>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="changeText(this)" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required="required" class="input-txt" />
  </form>
</p>
<p>tabs of sentences</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab1')">Tab 1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab2')">Tab 2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Tab3')">Tab 3</button>
</div>

<div id="Tab1" class="tabcontent">
  <p>Hello, my name is <b><span class="initname";>First and Last</span></b> number 1 and I really wish all instances of my name would update when I type in the above text field.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tab2" class="tabcontent">
  <p>Welcome, my name is <b><span class="initname";>First and Last</span></b> number 2 and I really wish all instances of my name would update when I type in the above text field.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tab3" class="tabcontent">
  <p>Greetings, my name is <b><span class="initname";>First and Last</span></b> number 3 and I really wish all instances of my name would update when I type in the above text field.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments above the spaces in `id="..."` and `name="..."` attributes aren't helping, but the issue that you're having with your `changeText` function is the fact that you are using the same id for each element, id attributes need to be unique within the page.

`document.getElementById('initname')` will only ever find the first element with the id of "initname" in the page.

If you have multiple elements that you need to identify it is better if you give them a `class="initname"` and use `document.getElementsByClassName('initname')` or the more powerful `document.querySelectorAll('.initname')` to retrieve all the elements with that class and then loop through them all, as you are doing in your `openTab()` function.